# UITableView cell coordinates

Tags: iphone, objective-c

There is any way to get cell coordinates when pressing on cell?

I have UITableView and i want to show the activityIndicatorView on the cell that was pressed and for that i need the cell coordinates.

the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method dont provide this information.

one more thing , when i show the activityIndicatorView i want from the UITableView to be darker (like in UIAlertView )and when i finished to do some stuff i want to bring the light back . how can i do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] Should let you directly access the cell from the didSelectRowAtIndexPath.

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
[cell addSubview:myIndicator];
[myIndicator startAnimating];
```

Also, in this method, do all your manipulations to the rest of the table.

You don't need to bother with coordinates.

Comment: ok i try this but it put the myIndicator in the left side of the cell and not in the center.

any idea?

Comment: Read about uiviews, and read the apple documentation.  You need to set the frame of the indicator to be in the center of the cell...

Read.